# Setting up a button in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I run into the following issue:

I have an activity which is set up in the `landscape mode` in this way:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

And here is my `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="320dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how the result looks like:

http://i56.tinypic.com/21103ld.png

What I want is that button to be set up at the bottom of the screen(`!from my point of view`).

But I don't know how to achieve that.Thanks

EDIT1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="320dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

SOLUTION:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<SurfaceView android:layout_width="450dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/surface_camera"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="320dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set the property of the button as the android:layout_alignParentBottom=true in button view. and then try it.

Comment: No result, it looks the same!

Comment: Ok than you change the height & width of the view with fill_parent and then check it. At that time also use the property of the Button View as explain before.

Comment: the relativelayout which has covered button remove that relativelayout.It is very simple to understand.what's difficult with that

Comment: Look what I tried at EDIT1 and there is no difference....I can see the button but still on the upper side of my screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    /android">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip" android:id="@+id/first"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <SurfaceView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/first">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
        android:text="Take Photo" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try changing your layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/first"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1.0">

<SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />
</RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/first"
 >
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="320dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"

android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This way the button doesn't even appears on the screen

Comment: you have provided the height of surfaceview in fillparent, which means it will occupy the full screen. Try providing the height for surface view like this,android:layout_height="100dip"

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
        **android:layout_alignParentButtom="true"**

Comment: It's not that simple.First, my second layout with the button it appears on the high side of the screen and above all my whole activity is in landscape mode!

Comment: Y u used second relativelayout.remove that and use android:layout_alignParentButtom="true".You will get what you want.

Comment: I don't understand what you said.Could u be more clear.Thank you:)

Comment: Remove relative layout which has covered button and use  android:layout_alignParentButtom="true" as attribute of button got my point?